# react-router: How to use same route within different sub-paths?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to use react routing within my application with some variation.

The application is hosted via CloudFront pointing to S3 bucket.
To host different variations of the application, I have earlier pushed build to different paths on S3 and each one worked perfectly (when react routing was NOT used).

e.g.

```
myexample.com
myexample.com/path1
```

with S3 structure as:

```
/static/js/*
/static/css/*
/public/*
/index.html
/path1/static/js/*
/path1/static/css/*
/path1/index.html
/path1/public/*
```

To have this working, the following line was added in package.json

```
"homepage": ".",
```

Now, the application required two routes `'/'` and `'/params'`.
The former launches the home page for the application while the second one launches another page and also requires some query params.
This has been implemented as follows:

```
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
...
...
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<MainApp />} />
  <Route exact path="/params" element={<Params queryParams={queryParams} />} />
</Routes>
```

This worked fine for the application without any subPath but when a path is provided (e.g. `path1`), it didn't work as no route was explictly specified for this.

I am looking for a way so that I could have it working for different subpaths as well such as:

```
myexample.com/
myexample.com/params?p1=abc&p2=def
myexample.com/path1/
myexample.com/path1/params?p1=rst&p2=xyz
```

I tried adding the following:

```
<Route exact path="/:subPath" element={<MainApp />} />
<Route exact path="/:subPath/params" element={<Params queryParams={queryParams} />} />
```

but it doesn't work until I change the directory structure on S3 as follows.

Initially:

```
/path1/static/js/*
/path1/static/css/*
/path1/index.html
/path1/public/*
```

which helps to make `myexample.com/path1/` work

Added explicitly:

```
/path1/params/static/js/*
/path1/params/static/css/*
/path1/params/index.html
/path1/params/public/*
```

which helps to make `myexample.com/path1/params/?p1=rst&p2=xyz` work
(Notice extra `'/'` after params which is not required for the url without sub paths)

I'm not able to figure out if I am doing something wrong in react code or if I need to make some changes to S3.

Comment: Have you reviewed and followed the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#s3-and-cloudfront) for configuring the server to host/serve the app(s) correctly? It's unclear what the problem is because you never state what exactly isn't working. You've also not included a complete [mcve] of the frontend router/routing code so we can see what *can* be matched, and how/where. Can you [edit] to provide better details?